# Windows Messages Between Applications

Tags: c#, forms, message

Using C# in Visual Studio 2008, is there a way for one application to send out a message, and for the other program to do something in the event of that message? Say, a button click in one app causes the other app listening to perform code that puts a word  in a textbox or something.

Comment: Yes. There are many ways.

Comment: Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521066-01-17.aspx for example.

Comment: When you say, "Windows messages," do you mean messages sent with PostMessage and SendMessage, or are  you describing a more generic category of communication?  For instance, you could do this via TCP ports with a protocol like Ice (http://www.zeroc.com/)...

Comment: @N4TKD: are you saying C# events are able to work between applications?  If so, I need to brush up on my C#.

Comment: @adv12 delegates works yes. and delegate methods can transfer arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I'll look further into the delegates.

Comment: @N4TKD Okay, time for me to do some reading!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the basic concept for what you want to do is called [Inter Process Communication or IPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There are many ways to do it depending on your needs.

In C# there is also a abstraction layer you can use over several IPC methods called [Windows Communication Foundation or WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This allows you to make function calls just like you would any other class but the function executes on the remote machine instead of the local machine. This is very much like the old IPC method called [Remoteing or RPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but WCF has replaced that technology.