# How to instantiate a class from a running process

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-4.8, system.reflection, system.diagnostics

The scenario: We wrote a small program, let's call it MyLittleProggy.exe, that can be launched and it will continue to run, basically just idling.

MyLittleProggy.exe contains a public class Class1

Now we run AnotherProggy.exe

This is what we're trying to do:

1. Check whether MyLittleProggy.exe is currently running, I assume by using System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName - no need to explain this, but let's just say I find the Process so I know MyLittleProggy is running.
2. Create a new instance of Class1 in this running process

Both applications will be written for .NET Framework 4.8

Is this possible and if so, how do I go about it? Do I work from the Process object I find, using its Modules, perhaps? Or do I need to use System.Reflection? Please note I am not looking for a fully worked out example, just a few pointers in the right direction as I am currently a bit lost in the weeds, and as a result I am also not sure how to ask the right questions so please be kind.... I'd be happy with short snippets of code in either C# or VB

Thank you

Comment: If the classes are meant to be shared you should put the sharable class into a library (dll) and your exe as well as any other app can create those class object.

Comment: Unless you open communication channels between the two processes, you cannot just instantiate a new object on the other process - for multiple reasons.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? What you suggest is not possible in any simple way, but you might have other options if we knew your scenario.

Comment: Typical keyword to search for would be "DLL injection" when you want todo something in a different process then yours. As a starter this was the first one i found https://easyhook.github.io/tutorials/remotefilemonitor.html

Comment: "explain why you want to do this" Yes, no problem. We wrote the original MyLittleProggy.exe which is currently called with a command line parameter. We find this sluggish; it takes a lot of time to "instantiate" certain things before MyLittleProggy can go do what we want it to do. What I would like to do is start up MyLittleProggy so it does all this "instantiation" and then instead of calling it with a command line parameter, call a method in it through "Class1". That way all the "instantiation" will already have been done and "doing what we want it to do" will be much quicker.

Comment: If it is acceptable to have "new Class1();" line of code MyLittleProggy, then I think it worth to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro - send a message from AnotherProggy that would trigger that "new Class1()" in MyLittleProggy

Comment: "Unless you open communication channels" - yes I am thinking that that is the best solution. I could use COM but I would rather avoid that if I can. If there is a *simple* way of doing this, yes, that would be a great solution.

Comment: I looked at @sarh's link and it confirms my initial impression of WCF seeing comments like "If WCF is the "simplest method", I really want to cry :P" ....

Comment: If you need to interact with the object between the 2 processes, then you can try with System.Remoting. If instead you only need to trigger the obejct creation and let the target process work alone, you can try also Windows Messaging or tcp sockets. check [CP](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20874/Inter-process-communication-via-Remoting), [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30838908/2629311), [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23572395/2629311), [SO3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1777668/2629311), [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/sockets/socket-services)

Comment: I would consider using powershell, It should let you create a reusable object from your assembly that you can use for multiple calls. It will likely require a bit of knowledge of .net and powershell, but you may be able to create script files, or other tools that make this easier.

Comment: So in a nutshell, you want `AnotherProggy` to notify `MyLittleProggy` each time it is launched. There are many ways to do this. One of the simpler ways is a named Semaphore or one of its relatives.

Comment: "The scenario: We wrote a small program, let's call it MyLittleProggy.exe, that can be launched and it will continue to run, basically just idling." kind of describes a "service"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you two options, one that simply notifies `MyLittleProggy` each time `AnotherProggy` launches, and a second that sends data from `AnotherProggy` to `MyLittleProggy`.

For the "notification only" version, we'll use a named event. Here's `MyLittleProggy`:

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    Console.WriteLine("I just started up")

    Dim namedEvent As New EventWaitHandle(False, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "MyExampleEvent")
    Console.WriteLine("I just finished one-time initialization")

    For i = 1 To 5
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting to be notified that other app started")
        namedEvent.WaitOne()
        Console.WriteLine("I just got notified that the other app started")
    Next

    namedEvent.Dispose()
    Console.WriteLine("I just quit")
End Sub
```

And here's `AnotherProggy`:

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    Console.WriteLine("AnotherProggy just started")

    Dim namedEvent As New EventWaitHandle(False, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "MyExampleEvent")
    Console.WriteLine("Initialization done")

    namedEvent.Set()
    Console.WriteLine("Just triggered event")

    namedEvent.Dispose()
    Console.WriteLine("I quit")
End Sub
```

This method uses an event that can be referenced by name by any program. The "heavy" `MyLittleProggy` does its heavy initialization once and then waits until something else triggers the event. The "light" application just triggers the event.

Let's move on to the version that passes data. It uses a named pipe. Here's `MyLittleProggy`:

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    Console.WriteLine("I just started up")

    Dim namedPipe As New Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream("MyExamplePipe")
    Dim pipeReader As New StreamReader(namedPipe)
    Console.WriteLine("I just finished one-time initialization")

    For i = 1 To 5
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for other app to send data")
        namedPipe.WaitForConnection()
        Console.WriteLine("Reading data from other app")
        Dim pipeData = pipeReader.ReadToEnd()
        Console.WriteLine($"Data from other app: {pipeData}")
        namedPipe.Disconnect()
    Next

    pipeReader.Dispose()
    namedPipe.Dispose()
    Console.WriteLine("I just quit")
End Sub
```

And here's `AnotherProggy`:

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    Console.WriteLine("I just started")

    Dim namedPipe As New Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream("MyExamplePipe")
    Dim writer As New StreamWriter(namedPipe)
    Console.WriteLine("Initialization done")

    namedPipe.Connect()
    writer.Write("Hello")
    writer.Flush()
    Console.WriteLine("Just sent data")

    Console.WriteLine("Cleaning up")
    writer.Dispose()
    namedPipe.Dispose()
    Console.WriteLine("Quit")
End Sub
```

Conceptually this is very similar to the first example - you wait on an object to tell you when the lightweight application was launched. The difference here is that you are waiting on a pipe connection instead of a named event, and then you read from the pipe.

Hopefully this is enough to get you started.